# Calculate diameter of metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

Calculate the diameter of space $ \left( \mathbb{R} , d \right) $ , where $ d : \mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R} $ is defined $
d(x,y) = \left|\left(\frac{x}{1+ \sqrt{ 1 + x^2}} - \frac{y}{1+ \sqrt{1 + y^2}}\right)\right|
$
I don't even know how to start.

Comment: You have a left parenthesis without a matching right.  Do you mean by \abs to be the absolute value of the ensuing expression?

Comment: Thanks, i have edited it. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Is this what you mean, user560461?  Any argument under the square root sign, e.g. in $\sqrt{1+x^2}$, we surround in braces, as follows: `\sqrt{1 + x^2}`

Comment: See if you can find a definition of the diameter of a set in your notes/coursebook. When in doubt, always go back to the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}-\frac{y}{1+\sqrt{1+y^2}} \right| \leq \frac{|x|}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}+\frac{|y|}{1+\sqrt{1+y^2}} \leq 2
\end{align}